# Why is there no electron-positron plasma around proton?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, plasma-physics, pair-production

When electric field approaches Schwinger limit:
$$
E_{cr}=\frac{m_e^2c^3}{e\hbar}\approx 1.32\times10^{18}~\text{V/m},
$$
in the presence of such field electron-positron pairs will be spontaneously created.
It is easy to estimate the radius at which the Coulomb field of a proton becomes equal to $E_{cr}$:
$$
E_{cr}=\frac{e}{r^2},
$$
thus
$$
r=\sqrt{\alpha}\frac{\hbar}{mc}\approx 3.4~\text{femtometer}
$$
According to google proton size is about $0.84$ femtometer, so we should expect electron-positron plasma to be created around proton and possible a plasma-like shielding effect.

Is there such an effect? If not why? And if it is present and my question is wrong, does this plasma affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I wasn't previously aware of this way of explaining a few effects. In the end, I conclude that the effect you're describing should give rise to (1) a small perturbation to the proton mass (2) a rare contribution to the proton parton distribution function (3) the Darwin term in the fine structure of Hydrogen.

First I want to dispel any possible notion of "quantum fluctuations" and by extension "spontaneous pair production." A proton is a distinct, unchanging object, whose mass is fixed and well defined. It doesn't "quantum fluctuate" as $e^+e^-$ pairs are generated around it. But your question brings up an interesting point, which I wasn't previously aware of: the proton's mass is slightly perturbed by the existence of the fermionic field for electrons (the quantum field whose excitations are called electrons). The unchanging quantum state describing a single proton (a Hamiltonian eigenstate) includes some states with one or more electron/positron pairs (if it is written in the particle-number basis instead of the Hamiltonian eigenstate basis).

But note that it should never be described as a "plasma" of thousands of electrons and positrons... in a very handwavy sense, once you've created one electron near the proton and one positron far away, you no longer have the electric field neccessary to create a second pair - the electric field of the proton has been eliminated by the electron.

In other words, there should be electrons and positrons in the [parton distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_(particle_physics)) for protons. Usually when you collide two protons, it's not the entire protons that collide, but just one particle which constitutes some of the proton's mass... up quarks, down quarks, and gluons mostly. But occassionally also strange quarks, and although I can't find records of it being observed, it should occasionally be electrons and positrons by your argument. It won't be on typical plots of the PDF because (1) it will be suppressed by (at least?) $\alpha^2$, because the Feynman diagram will need two electromagnetic vertices, and it will constitute a very low momentum fraction $O(m_e/m_p)$

First, note that the classical electron radius $e^2/4\pi\epsilon_0 m_ec^2=2.8\text{ fm}$ is the same as your Schwinger limit distance (not a coincidence). And in our derivation of the Darwin term, one of the [fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure) corrections to the energy levels of Hydrogen, we average the potential from the proton seen by the electron over a length scale given by the classical electron radius. Early descriptions of this called it a "fast quantum fluctuation" of the electron's position. More modern descriptions say that there is a Feynman diagram in bound state QED that describes pair production of an electron and a positron from a photon emitted by the nucleus, and that smoothes the potential seen by the electron.
[see page 5 in [these notes](https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/notes/finestruc.pdf)]

So I think the answer is, yes, there is an experimental observation arising from your back of the envelope calculation, and it is the Darwin term.

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that there is vacuum polarization near an electron, there is also vacuum polarization (including creation of electron-positron pairs) near a proton.

> Exact calculations have shown that the effects of vacuum polarization
> on S-wave p-p scattering are of the same order of magnitude as the
> experimental errors. The effective range analysis for the proton case
> gives a slightly better fit when the effect is explicitly included.

(M W Kermode 1968 J. Phys. A: Gen. Phys. 1 236).

And I don't think the Darwin term is related to vacuum polarization near the proton, as @AXensen believes.

Comment: I think you might be right about the Darwin term. Since it comes from the Dirac equation and it gives a correction to every potential of the form $\nabla^2V$, it might be best phrased as a property of the electron, not the proton (unless it's a property of the potential?). But I'm leaving it in my answer because at the very least the phenomena are very similar - it's about diagrams involving pair creation affecting potentials on length scales smaller than the classical electron radius.

Comment: So when we have a charged particle (like proton) we can treat vacuum 'around it' as some kind of matter with refractive index, right? And we only need one 'real' electron to counter the proton's charge. Is is the following interpretation correct: the proton is 'surrounded' by virtual electron-positron pairs, and those virtual electrons are attracted to it, creating a slight screening effect. In other words, we 'smear' one electron around proton, slightly reducing its charge.

Comment: @aii : You are asking a lot of questions:-)  "And we only need one 'real' electron to counter the proton's charge" I am not sure. There is an electron in a hydrogen atom, but that does not mean there is no vacuum polarization there. "slight screening effect" I am not sure. The effect can be huge. In QFT, bare particles can have infinite charge, but it becomes finite after renormalization(which, I believe, takes vacuum polarization into account.